# Update Status of current location -iOS

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6

How can I get this small thumbnail status on the right corner of the icon?

[image: Fahreneit application as shown below]

Comment: Are you looking for `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:68];`?

Comment: You should really clarify your question.  Which icon are talking about, what do you want to accomplish?

Comment: Duplicate of some posts. 

example: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790903/badge-on-app-icon-in-iphone-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:` method to set the badge to any number you want. This message should be sent to an instance of `UIApplication`. To get the current application, you simply call `[UIApplication sharedApplication]`.

Your code would look like this:

```
int number = 25; //set this to any number you want

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:number];
```

Or, you can obviously set it at once, without the extra variable, like this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:25];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use application badge to set like that.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:68];
```

For more reference, see [this](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/user-interface/using-application-badges.html)

Also see [UIApplication documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIApplication/applicationIconBadgeNumber)

Comment: can we chance iconbadgeNumber background color?

Answer (score 0):

For the badge see

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIApplication/applicationIconBadgeNumber or use

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:68];
```

For the **new** icon, you can't this is done by apple when you download a new application and it hasn't been opened yet.

Comment: can we chance iconbadgeNumber background color? default is red but I would like to make it green.

Comment: @user1724168 No you cannot. At least not with apples public API's